# Regular expression for GCC Pre Processor Line markers

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any Bash or Python regular expression for below C pre processor line marker ?

C Pre Processor output line markers as follows:

```
# 74 "a/b/some_file.c" 3 4
```

First comes the symbol - #
space
then line number - 74
space
then - "file path"
space
then Zero or more integers separated by space - 3 4

More info on:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

Comment: "Is there" = "Write it for me" ?

Comment: As @EugeneSh. said, because you just wrote the regular expression in common language. Just needs translation, and reading any manual or tutorial will allow you to write this.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Also Google "regex tester". You can try things online to test your regex ideas.

Comment: thanks  @lurker your comment is the most useful and helpful above all other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno where you'd want Bash to match such lines, and Python undoubtedly could do it with its regexes.  I have a `sed` script which I use to convert `#line` directives into comments (which can sometimes make debugging preprocessed code easier).  It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# @(#)$Id: linecomments.sh,v 1.3 2018/01/05 05:12:10 jleffler Exp $
#
# Convert #line directives into comments
# Deals with four forms of the #line directive:
#           # line 99 "file"
#           # line 99
#           # 99 "file"
#           # 99

exec sed \
    -e 's%^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*line[[:space:]][0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]].*%/*&*/%' \
    -e 's%^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]].*%/*&*/%' \
    -e 's%^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*line[[:space:]][0-9][0-9]*$%/*&*/%' \
    -e 's%^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*[0-9][0-9]*$%/*&*/%' \
    "$@"
```

I use `%` to delimit the regular expressions since I need `/*` and `*/` in the replacement text. The regexes match 'trailing junk' such as the extra numbers emitted by GCC.

The edit in 2018 replaced fragments that looked like `[  ]` with `[[:space:]]` — the old code (dated 2001) used a blank and a tab in each case.  This is clearer; you can copy'n'paste without having to worry about where there are tabs.